# Scaling images in html and scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Good afternoon. I have a large picture of 6000x3000px which I scale using scale(0.3). It is required that the image is scaled to a certain point, different each time.

I implemented first scaled, and then scrollTo scroll, but it looks crooked and the picture jumps. how can this be implemented easier and more correctly. React TS HTML CSS stack

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const x = selectedSection?.dot?.position.x ? selectedSection?.dot.position.x - 1440 : 1430
        const y = selectedSection?.dot?.position.y ? selectedSection?.dot.position.y - 540 : 1820

        isZoom ? containerRef.current?.scrollTo(x, y) : containerRef.current?.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }, [isZoom, selectedSection])
```

Comment: try this? https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker/

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus yes, that's how it should work, but it's a map